# Django REST API don't see a URL

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-404

I think I have an import problem.  After learning through all the tutorials and was able to get up to this point.  I just want to see my database with .objects.all().  The problem is the code 404 where it can't see "receipts.url"

makemigrate  and migrate is all done without any issues.
server was running with access to admin.

I am getting this problem, but I have it all mapped out.  Please help and thanks again.

```
"Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/receipts/
Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
receipts/ [name='all']
The current path, receipts/, didn’t match any of these."
```

My project name is "project", my app name is "receipts".  "project", "receipts" and "manage.py" all are in the same level.

I can see my database in the admin page, and as well as Mongodb compass.
Here are all of my files:

project/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'receipts',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('receipts/', include('receipts.urls')),
]
```

receipts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import CustomersViews

urlpatterns = [
    path(" ", CustomersViews.as_view(), name='all'),
```

receipts/views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .serializers import CustomerSerializer
from .models import Customer

class CustomersViews(APIView):

    def get_all(self, request):
        customers = Customer.objects.all()
        serializer = CutomerSerializer(customers, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

receipts/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Customer


class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('firstname',
                  'lastname',
                  'date',
                  'address',
                  )
```

Comment: I think it's a typo, you have an extra space in your path: `path(" ", CustomersViews.as_view(), name='all')` should be `path("", CustomersViews.as_view(), name='all')`

Comment: alright!! thanks @R. Uziel.  Now I can see a "Django REST Framework" page.

Comment: hi @R.Uziel now I am getting a 405 error.  "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."  Where do you think I have the problem, and I can read more about it.  thanks.

Comment: solved it.  Don't know why it had that issue.  thanks.

Comment: Great.  My guess was that you had no `def get(self, request):` in your CustomersViews, and I'm not at all familiar with a `get_all(self, request)` method.

Comment: @R.Uziel I think it was a typo at one of the functions.  Thanks again.